# different version of Python libraries in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

I am working on VSCode and I am trying to update the `scikit-learn` library. However, I have this confusion in the terminal.

```
user$ conda list scikit-learn
# packages in environment at /Users/ahmedelashry/opt/anaconda3/envs/mygoshaba:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
scikit-learn              1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi

user$ python 
Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 26 2021, 10:16:00) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn

>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.24.2'

>>> sklearn.show_versions()

System:
    python: 3.7.10 (default, Feb 26 2021, 10:16:00)  [Clang 10.0.0 ]
executable: /Users/ahmedelashry/opt/anaconda3/envs/mygoshaba/bin/python
   machine: Darwin-21.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

Python dependencies:
          pip: 20.2.4
   setuptools: 60.9.2
      sklearn: 0.24.2
        numpy: 1.21.2
        scipy: 1.7.1
       Cython: 0.29.26
       pandas: 1.3.3
   matplotlib: 3.4.2
       joblib: 1.1.0
threadpoolctl: 2.2.0

Built with OpenMP: True
```

The terminal environment is the same as the one I use in VSCode. I tried to restart VSCode and it is the same thing. Any body had this issue before and how can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: That looks like system python vs. conda environments - you can certainly have different versions of packages. Is this a problem?

Comment: No. The conda environment I am working with is the same one I activate in the terminal before my attached snippet.

Comment: per https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html *Scikit-learn 1.0 supported Python 3.7-3.10. Scikit-learn 1.1 and later requires Python 3.8 or newer* This might be an issue - a little at a loss how to explain how but at least it seems that you shouldn't actually be able to use sklearn 1.2 on python 3.7.10 anyway.

Comment: I didn't get the last part of your comment, but the two versions in the snippet are 0.24 and 1.0 and so this limitation shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Well let me try again. Per https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html  *Scikit-learn 1.1 and later requires Python 3.8 or newer*. Your environment is Python 3.7. So trying to use Scikit-learn 1.2 on Python 3.7.10 could be a problem.

Comment: Of course, what confused me is that I wasn't trying to use Scikit-learn 1.2, I want to use version 1.0 of it which is compatible with my environment. But really, the main point in my question is that why do I have two differet version of scikit-learn outside and inside python as you see in my snippet?

Comment: Of course that is a mystery but I would recommend starting by at least installing 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.2 since 1.0.2 is not compatible with python 3.7.10 - I am assuming you have 1.0.2 installed because of the first line in your output. Often when my conda environments get wonky I just scratch them out an start fresh.

Comment: That's probably it. When I tried to install 1.0.0, I ended up with so many conflicts, so I decided to go fresh. Thank you for your comments!